# How to set variables for php.ini & session.php for subdomains with HTTPS to use shared sessions?

Tags: php, session, ssl, https, opencart2.x

I use Opencart 2.2.0.0 with SSL. And I have 3 sub-domains also covered with SSL. I need to use shared session on all sites (login and cart).
No matter what I try, I couldn't manage to set the variables for `php.ini` and `session.php`. There are millions of different versions or solutions on web so I am confused. Some even suggesting cross-domains.

If you can help me, I really appreciate it. We might have the chance to disable one domain's ssl in the near future. So we will be more happy if your solution covers both.

Comment: You got full access to your server? and what type of server are you using?

Comment: What did you try so far? Post your code! What happened when you ran it? What did you expect to happen instead? What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: my php.ini is as follows :  safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.auto_start = Off;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 3600;
allow_url_fopen = on;

Comment: public function start($session_id = '', $key = 'default') {
  if (!session_id()) {
   ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
   ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
   ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
   ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'Off');
   
  
   if ($session_id) {
    session_id($session_id);
   } 
    
   if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,52}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    exit('Error: Invalid session ID!');
   }

Comment: Try one of the solutions on the web, and if it works for you, great. If not you can post it here and ask why it isn't doing what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation you have to enable **CORS (Cross-origin Resource Sharing)**

You did not mention which server type you are using, so I can only show you where to begin, there are multiple solutions for different server types.

- https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled
- http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: I use ubuntu 14 on gcloud. it was working before we upgraded from 2.1.0.2 to 2.2.0.0 and add sll to all domains. But I will work on cors. thank you fro your interest.